# SQL query to calculate subtotal on column

Tags: sql

I have a table which have two column say Column1 and Column2.
Column1 comprises of Key and Column2 comprises of Values.

I have to display all key-value pair along with key-group sum.

Currently I am ordering the values by Column1 and calculating sum for each key in view using a local variable.

Can this be merged in a single SQL query.

Please see below image for further diagrammatic view.

[image]

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Please post your current query as text instead of an image.

Comment: `Group by Grouping Sets ((Col1),(Col1,Col2))` or withrollup depending on rdbms

Answer (score 2):

Yiou can use union all ordered

```
 select column1  , column2
 from my_table 
 union all  
 select concat(column1, ' - Sub Total') as column1, sum(column2) 
 from my_table 
 group by column1
 order by column1
```

Comment: But he want `column1` to be `sub total`

Comment: I know, I mean it should contain the value - `sub total`

Comment: Or use Name of the column concat  'sub total' or add the order for presentation .. in may answer i use the column1 and concat for order .. otherwise is needed a ordere column